# How to get the random salt from password_hash in PHP?

Tags: php, php-password-hash

I've read in the manual that the PHP-function `password_hash()` uses a random salt to hash the password. How to get this random salt for saving it to database?

Comment: Why do you need this salt?

Comment: The salt is part of the generated hash, and generated randomly every time. You shouldn't be saving it separately, and you shouldn't be modifying/fixing it. Leave it alone! Just use `password_hash` as instructed in the docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A salt is generated automatically and randomly when you run `password_hash`. It will be different every time, even for the same password. **That's good!** From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.password.storing-salts):

[image]

**You should not manually set or in any way modify the salt**. Just save the entire hash in the database, and let PHP handle it. `password_hash` and `password_verify`, by default, use the industry standard `bcrypt` algorithm in a manner complying with industry best practices. Modifying that behavior is likely to make your site **less** secure.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple, look here: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.password.storing-salts

But actually you shouldn't need it, because password_verify() doesn't need the salt manually.

Comment: if you're going to reference PHP.net, at the very least use an English version of it http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.password.storing-salts - Edit: This as per your original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38553031/1

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're right. I didn't noticed that I was on the German site.